# A limit of a sequence of probabilities related to the Binomial Distribution/ Law of large numbers

Tags: probability, limits, binomial-distribution

I currently have the problem to establish that
$
\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n\cdot l\rfloor}   \binom{n}{k} (s)^k(1-s)^{n-k} 
=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if}~l< s\\
1, & \text{if}~l\geq s
\end{cases}
$

I know I have to use the law of large numbers and it looks a lot like the binomial distribution. For that I know that:
$
\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \sum_{k=0}^{n}   \binom{n}{k} (s)^k(1-s)^{n-k} 
=\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} (1-s+s)^n=1
$

The $l$ term in the upper bound of the sum absolutly confuses me.
Can anyone help me how to show this in a mathematically nice way?

Comment: Your $\lfloor n\cdot l\rfloor$ looks like $\lfloor n- l\rfloor$ rather then the $\lfloor n l\rfloor$ it is supposed to be. The values of $s$ and $l$ are probably restricted to the interval $[0,1]$ so this is the binomial probability of being at $\lfloor n l\rfloor$ or below, and you may need the Central Limit Theorem. The point of the limit is whether the points around the mean $ns$ is included in the sum or not for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it. 
So what I basicly asked is:
Let $X \sim Bi(n,s)$ then
$X\overset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} E(X)=ns$ 
Therefore
$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(X \leq ns)=...$(see above)

Now I only dont know how to write that down nicely so everybody understands it instantly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think its understandable and mathematically correct to write:
$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X \leq nl)=lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(E(X) \leq nl) =lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(ns \leq nl)= 0$, if $l <s$ and 1 if $l \geq s$

Comment: You have to prove it.  You could assume a normal approximation and look at the standard deviation.

Comment: could you explain a bit further what you mean by that? What eyactly should I show how? Thank you btw for helping!

Answer (score 1):

We will address the only interesting case, that is, $0<s<1$. Let $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence where $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=s$ and $\mathbb P(X_1=0)=1-s$ and let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Then by the central limit theorem and the fact that the limiting distribution has a continuous c.d.f, we infer that
$$\tag{*}
\sup_{t\in\mathbb R}\left\vert \mathbb P\left(\frac{S_n-\mathbb E[S_n]}{\operatorname{Var(S_n)}} \leqslant t\right)-\mathbb P(N\leqslant t)\right\rvert\to 0,
$$
where $N$ has a standard normal distribution.

We are looking for the limit of $\mathbb P(S_n\leqslant \lfloor n\ell\rfloor)$. Using the fact that $\mathbb E[S_n]=ns$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_n)=ns(1-s)$, we are reduced, in view of (*), to find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(N\leqslant \frac{\lfloor n\ell\rfloor -ns}{\sqrt n\sqrt{s(1-s)}}\right).
$$
If $\ell<s$, then $\frac{\lfloor n\ell\rfloor -ns}{\sqrt n\sqrt{s(1-s)}}\to -\infty$ and the limit is indeed $0$.

If $\ell=s$, then $\frac{\lfloor n\ell\rfloor -ns}{\sqrt n\sqrt{s(1-s)}}\to 0$, because $\lvert \lfloor n\ell\rfloor -n\ell\rvert\leqslant 1$ hence the limit is $1/2$.

If $\ell>s$, then $\frac{\lfloor n\ell\rfloor -ns}{\sqrt n\sqrt{s(1-s)}}\to \infty$ hence the limit is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Chebyshev's inequality. If $X_n=B(n,s)$ (the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $s$) and $l<s$ then

$P(X_n\leq\lfloor nl\rfloor)=P(X_n\leq nl)\leq P(|X_n - ns|\geq n(s-l))$.

Thus, by Chebyshev's inequality, since $\mu_{X_n}=ns$ and $\sigma^2_{X_n}=ns(1-s)$,

$P(|X_n - ns|\geq n(s-l))\leq \frac{ns(1-s)}{n^2(s-l)^2}=\frac{s(1-s)}{n(s-l)^2}$.

It is clear that the right side converges to $0$.

On the other hand, when $s<l$,

$P(X_n\leq\lfloor nl\rfloor)=P(X_n\leq nl)\geq P(X_n< nl) \geq P(|X_n - ns|< n(l-s))$

and, by Chebyshev's inequality,

$\geq 1-\frac{ns(1-s)}{n^2(l-s)^2}=1-\frac{s(1-s)}{n(s-l)^2}$.

Cleary, the right side converges to $1$.

Comment: What about $l = s$? :)